# Is it appropriate to edit "very" old posts?

Tags: discussion, editing

I ended up [here](https://superuser.com/questions/95204/what-parts-i-need-to-assemble-my-own-computer) because it was in the related links [of a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/186239/are-laptops-assembled-by-hand). The original version made be pull a face, so I've adjusted it. However, given it has been accepted and unedited for about 7 months, is this appropriate?

I'm inclined to say the answer is **yes**, as long as it improves the site, but I would like some wider community confirmation please. Are there any cases where it is instead right to leave old posts alone, even if they can be improved?

Notice that someone has posted a new comment on the question because I've bumped it with my edit, for example. So are there any other potential issues here?

I'm not, I should say, intending to go trawling for old posts to fix...

Comment: Yes, [there's even a badge for that](http://superuser.com/help/badges/118/archaeologist).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you leave the meaning of the question as it is, then yes. If a question can be improved, then please do so as it will make searching easier for people that come here to look for answers. Of course, do mind the etiquette of editing.

Sometimes, questions are very old and about obsolete software or hardware. In that case, for example, do mind you're not making an Windows XP question about Windows 7 just because it deals with a seemingly similar problem in MS Word.

Comment: No, I'm always careful to avoid editing the meaning, but just wondered what the general feel on adjusting and bumping old posts was. Thanks.